# Not sure if code runs in parallel. Tasks in console application

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task

I have this code:

```
var dt = new DeveloperTest();
    var tasks = readers.Select(dt.ProcessReaderAsync).ToList();
    var printCounterTask = new Task(() => dt.DelayedPrint(output));
    printCounterTask.Start();

    Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(x => dt.Print(output).ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        dt.Finished = true;
    })).Wait();

    printCounterTask.Wait();
```

What this does is preparing tasks that will be run and then start a (I think ) parallel execution which starts with:

```
 printCounterTask.Start();
```

this is what delayed print does:

```
public async Task DelayedPrint(IOutputResult output)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (!Finished)
                {
                    //every 10 seconds should print. 
                    //at least one print even if the execution is less than 10 seconds
                    //as this starts in paralel with the processing
                    Task.Delay(10 * 1000).Wait();
                    await Print(output);
                }
                else
                {
#if DEBUG
                    Console.WriteLine("Finished with printing");
#endif
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically is printing some output that is delayed every 10 seconds, then when all the tasks are complete stops the infinite loop.
if you want to see the whole code is here https://github.com/velchev/Exclaimer-Test

I am not sure if this

```
Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(x => dt.Print(output).ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
            dt.Finished = true;
        })).Wait();
```

runs in parallel with   printCounterTask.Start();
When I debut it seems it does as a breakpoint in the !Finished code is hit and then in the else clause too. As far as I know when you start a task it runs in parallel so all the tasks should run in parallel. A task is a representation of a thread which syntactically is easier to control compared to the old syntax. So all this threads running and because of the better syntax is easier to say - wait till all finish and then change the flag. Any helpful explanation will be appreciated. Thank you mates.

Comment: Can you include the code of the `ProcessReaderAsync` method?

Comment: You're blocking all threads in ThreadPool by `Task.Delay().Wait()`. If all the tasks should run in parallel change that to `await Task.Delay()`.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann the `Task.Delay().Wait()` is part of the implementation of one task, the `printCounterTask`. The implementation of the `tasks` is not shown in the question (links to external sites doesn't count IMHO).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Oh - yeah. Missed that. Sorry. But OP should change that.

Comment: If you [use `Task.Run` instead of `new Task` and `Task.Start`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html), and [use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html#comment-4acb62b0-1a8f-11ea-9eca-ebd14bdc5874), your code will simplify significantly and be a lot clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is mostly correct as written, but there are some nuances around the `Task` constructor and `ContinueWith` that make it difficult to understand, and make it easy to break. For example, `printCounterTask.Wait()` will not wait until `DelayedPrint` completes, because the `Task` constructor does not understand asynchronous delegates.

To make the code fully correct and much easier to read and reason about, replace `new Task`/`Start` with `Task.Run`, and replace `ContinueWith` with `await`:

```
var dt = new DeveloperTest();
var tasks = readers.Select(dt.ProcessReaderAsync).ToList();
var printCounterTask = Task.Run(() => dt.DelayedPrint(output));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
await dt.Print(output);
dt.Finished = true;

await printCounterTask;
```

You will also find your code to be clearer if you follow the [convention of suffixing asynchronous methods with `Async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types).

> A task is a representation of a thread which syntactically is easier to control compared to the old syntax.

No, not at all. A task is a [Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) - a representation of an operation that may complete sometime in the future. This "operation" [does not necessarily require a thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). `Task.Run` does queue work to the thread pool, but in this example, the task does not always use a thread pool thread (specifically, it doesn't use a thread pool thread during the `await Task.Delay`).

Comment: Thanks I agree for the syntax is better with await not sure why I used the other way. Also yes thread and task are very different concepts, you can start async operation with task which uses thread from threadpool and there is a way to know when it is finished using the syntax. (for reference  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/task-and-thread-in-c-sharp/) Would you say that await Task.WhenAll(tasks); is not running in parallel and while printCounterTask is executing? To me it does run in parallel or at least asynchronously...

Comment: The tasks are running concurrently, yes. `await Task.WhenAll` doesn't actually *do* anything; it's just a point where the tasks are (asynchronously) waited on. Neither `await` nor `WhenAll` will actually cause additional tasks to run; they're just "join" points.

Comment: not sure why someone is voting even my question to -1.... this was an interview task for which I got this feedback "Multiple readers are not run in parallel which causes the output timer is not called until the end of the run failing the output every 10 seconds requirement." When testing and debugging I don't think that is correct but couldn't get more from the interviewer.

Comment: It's possible that they got confused due to the `Task` constructor and `ContinueWith`?

Comment: no idea... shouldn't be this the case as it seems they use one and the same test for all levels of software devs which means they are very very familiar with the question and possible solutions.

Answer (score -1):

You are partly right.
The tasks will run in parallel with

> printCounterTask

as expected.
However a task is not a representation of a thread and not a syntactic sugaring which easier to control over thread.
Here you can find a useful information:
https://www.dotnetforall.com/difference-task-and-thread/

In general it's important for you to understand that Tasks are using Threads from the ThreadPool.

A task is a representation of a method you wish to execute as a background work (you don't want to block the current execution), and a task needs a thread in order to operate, but it's not true that a task is a thread.

You may have more tasks than available threads in the thread pool, which will lead to them waiting in the queue for available thread in order to be executed.

Also take in consideration that Task.WhenAll will not execute the tasks for you, you'll have to execute them yourself (implementation of ProcessReaderAsync is missing, but if you're using Task.Run it's OK).